# Changing temperature range in thermographic map using QGIS

Tags: qgis, maps, weather

I need to know how to set temperature range from thermographic map to be from 100-120° C using QGIS. In that case I would see just the temperatures from 100-120° C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the raster style setting, set the contrast enhancment to Stretch and Clip to MinMax, and set the minimum and Maximum values to your desired range

[image]